# Android Studio was unable to create a local connection

Tags: android-studio

I got the error below after not use Android Studio for a few days.

Any way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Are you the only user logged in? Maybe another user is using the system, try a restart...always works ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. Run cmd.exe as admin
2. Type netsh winsock reset
3. Restart Android Studio

And you will no longer get this error :)